# Converting the colors in decompiled Android

Tags: android, colors

How do we convert the colors in decompiled android?

For example: we decompile the apk android, the last to use jd-gui view. Class files, and found the decompiled int color = -65536;

What is the original (hexadecimal) color in this case? How do we convert hexadecimal -65536 to the originally defined color (format 0x1ABCDE)?

Comment: How sad, if you are decompiling an app to look for color code... Instead, should not be learning basics first?

Answer (score 1):

You mean just for knowing which color it is? Or just to get it into the same format simply for printing the value of it?

One way would be use the built in `Integer.toHexString()` method:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(-65536);

// output is probably something like: ffff0000
```

But it's a string. The fact of the matter is that the -65536 value is actually the color. You can assign it to something to see that it actually works.

Comment: The negative value might mean that there is some transparency involved. The best thing is to try out.

Answer (score 0):

The color comes from the `android.graphics.Color` class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RED